# Core location returning 0 as altitude

Tags: swift, swift3, core-location

Look here [Finding Altitude in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728085/finding-altitude-in-swift)
And look my code

```
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var alt: Double?

    @IBOutlet weak var coor: UILabel!

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
        alt = newLocation.altitude
        var altitude = locationManager.location?.altitude
        print("\(altitude)")
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    @IBAction func getCoor(_ sender: Any) {
        var altitude = locationManager.location?.altitude
        coor.text = "\(altitude)"
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it show me the actual altitude instead always shows 0.0?

Comment: What is your altitude? What lat and long does it return? Is the location nil? Is there actually a location? Are you running on a device on on the simulator?

Comment: Is it swift 3 ?

Comment: Yes , Me I have to code it in swift 3

Comment: Did you implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol? What I mean is... saving every concurrent location? Every location update will have more accuracy.

Comment: Are you testing on real device and not simulator ? Also, do you have location (lat/long)?

Comment: @JonyDoe don't just stop the location manager when it receives a location, but let it simply work in the background. Wait, for example, 10 iterations and see if it gets updated accordingly.

Comment: @Larme, in a real device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CLLocationManager delegate methods are not getting called(google maps is integrated)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718552/cllocationmanager-delegate-methods-are-not-getting-calledgoogle-maps-is-integra)

Comment: I had the same issue using the simulator. Altitude is non-zero when using a real device.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of code is doomed to failure:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
    // ...
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Having started the location manager with `startUpdatingLocation`, you're stopping the location manager on the very first call to `didUpdateLocation`. But the first call is always bogus, and even the next dozen calls or so are likely to be just warmups as the hardware obtains a fix.

If your question is "where am I", use `requestLocation`, not `startUpdatingLocation`. It calls into `didUpdateLocation` only once, and only when it actually *does* have a good enough location (which may take some time).

Finally, note that your code is not correct in Swift 3. `locationManager(manager:...)` will *never* be called. [Read the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager) to learn the correct signature.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing newlocation.altitude into "alt" variable, but printing "altitude".

Try: `print("\(alt)")`